# How do I populate HTML form with database values when I click edit button?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I want to populate form fields with database values when I click the edit button. The form I want to populate is responsible for updating a diary entry's attributes (which comprise of title and body).

Currently when I click the edit button, I get an empty edit form. Therefore, if I want to retain some existing information on the entry (for example the body of the entry), I have to copy the body of the entry into the edit form before I update the entry which is a cumbersome task.

How do I go about implementing this?

**Function for updating a diary entry**

```
function edit_entry(entry_id){
    // open modal to edit diary entry
    var modal = document.getElementById('edit_modal');

    modal.style.display = "block";

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    };
    document.getElementById('edit_modal').addEventListener('submit', updateDetail);

    function updateDetail(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let title = document.getElementById('title').value;
        let body = document.getElementById('body').value;

        var statusCode;

        fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/entries/'+parseInt(entry_id),{
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.getItem('token')
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "title": title,
                "body": body,
            })    
        })
        .then((result) => {    
            statusCode = result.status;
            return result.json();
        })
        .then((data) =>{    
            window.alert(data.message);
            modal.style.display = "none";
            redirect: window.location.replace('./viewAllEntries.html');    
        });    
    }    
}
```

**HTML form**

```
<form action="" class ="add-content" id="edit_modal">    
    <h2>My Diary | Edit Entry <i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label></label>
        <textarea id = "title" class ="input-control"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label></label>
        <textarea id = "body" class ="input-control">  </textarea>
    </div>

    <div class ="form-group">
        <label>&nbsp</label>
        <button type = "submit" class ="button button-block" />Save <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is this what you are getting at?

document.querySelector('#edit_modal .title').value = data.title;

document.querySelector('#edit_modal .body').value = data.body;

Comment: Yes.I want the edit form to contain current title and body values of an entry.Right now the form that pops up is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the modal just grab the data for the entry from your API. Try something like the code below.

$yourUrlToFetchTheData should be the url of the api route to fetch the data you need.

```
fetch($yourUrlToFetchTheData, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
    })
    .then((result) => {
        // TODO FILL THE TEXTAREAS WITH THE VALUES OF THE RESULT.
        $("title").text(result.json.title);
        $("body").text(result.json.body);

    })
    .then((data) => {
        // TODO DO SOMETHING WITH THE ERROR.
    });
```

Put this code after **modal.style.display = "block";** and modify it a bit!